# App freezes when opening 2 Sweet Alert Dialogs in a row

Tags: java, android, freeze

First of all I'm a noob, this is literally the first app im trying to make (i've learned java just a few days ago thru youtube videos) so don't be hard on me if its a simple thing xD.

Ok, im making this app that plays a random note and then it gives you a bunch of buttons with the name of the notes and you have to select which one you think is the note that is playing.

For this, i've implemented this dialogs that appear when you press the buttons and tell you if you're right or wrong. BUT when i press a button and the dialog shows up, i close it and press another button, and the app FREEZES like, it doesn't even crash, it is still running in my phone and in Android studio, but the app just freezes there and I can't do anything else. if you could help me reviewing my code and tell me where i failed?.

this is the first activity, which is just a button that makes you go to the second activity where the note plays and the buttons appear:

```
    package com.tetdevs.randomizer;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


    import android.content.Intent;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button randomButton;



    //Button opens another activity
    randomButton =  findViewById(R.id.button);
    randomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openSecondActivity();


        }

    });


}


//Method that opens the other activity
public void openSecondActivity () {
    Intent openSecondActivity = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(openSecondActivity);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);


}

}
```

Second activity:

```
 package com.tetdevs.randomizer;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;


 import java.util.Random;

 import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {





int[] sounds = {R.raw.c3, R.raw.c4, R.raw.c5, R.raw.cs3, R.raw.cs4, R.raw.cs5,
        R.raw.d3, R.raw.d4, R.raw.d5, R.raw.ds3, R.raw.ds4, R.raw.ds5,
        R.raw.e3, R.raw.e4, R.raw.e5, R.raw.f3, R.raw.f4, R.raw.f5,
        R.raw.fs3, R.raw.fs4, R.raw.fs5, R.raw.g3, R.raw.g4, R.raw.g5,
        R.raw.gs3, R.raw.gs4, R.raw.gs5, R.raw.a3, R.raw.a4, R.raw.a5,
        R.raw.as3, R.raw.as4, R.raw.as4, R.raw.b3, R.raw.b4, R.raw.b5};

Random r = new Random();
int Low=0;
int High =35;
int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low)+Low;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Button buttonCs;
    final Button buttonD;
    final Button buttonDs;
    final Button buttonE;
    final Button buttonF;
    final Button buttonFs;
    final Button buttonG;
    final Button buttonGs;
    final Button buttonA;
    final Button buttonAs;
    final Button buttonB;
    final Button playAgain;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    NotePlayer notes = new NotePlayer();
    notes.SoundPlayer(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);

    Button buttonC = findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    buttonCs =  findViewById(R.id.buttonCsharp);
    buttonD =  findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    buttonDs = findViewById(R.id.buttonDsharp);
    buttonE =  findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
    buttonF =  findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
    buttonFs = findViewById(R.id.buttonFsharp);
    buttonG =  findViewById(R.id.buttonG);
    buttonGs = findViewById(R.id.buttonGsharp);
    buttonA =  findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    buttonAs = findViewById(R.id.buttonAsharp);
    buttonB =  findViewById(R.id.buttonB);

    playAgain =  findViewById(R.id.playAgain);

    final SweetAlertDialog yay = new SweetAlertDialog(SecondActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
    final SweetAlertDialog nay = new SweetAlertDialog(SecondActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);


    playAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotePlayer.player.start();
        }
    });

    buttonC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 1 || rndm == 2 || rndm == 3 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();

            }
        }
    });
    buttonCs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 4 || rndm == 5 || rndm == 6 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();

            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 7 || rndm == 8 || rndm == 9 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonDs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 10 || rndm == 11 || rndm == 12 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
        }
        }
    });
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 13 || rndm == 14 || rndm == 15 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 16 || rndm == 17 || rndm == 18 ){

                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();

            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonFs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 19 || rndm == 20 || rndm == 21 ){

                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();

            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(rndm == 22 || rndm == 23 || rndm == 24 ){
                    yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                    yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                    yay.show();

            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonGs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(rndm == 25 || rndm == 26 || rndm == 27 ){

                    yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                    yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                    yay.show();

            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }

        }
    });
    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 28 || rndm == 29 || rndm == 30 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonAs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 31 || rndm == 32 || rndm == 33 ){
                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rndm == 34 || rndm == 35 || rndm == 36 ){

                yay.setTitle("Yay!");
                yay.setContentText("Yesss");
                yay.show();


            }
            else {
                nay.setTitle("nay: :(");
                nay.setContentText("Not quite!");
                nay.show();
            }
        }
    });





}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent Intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    finish();

}


@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();


    //stops player when switching activities
    if (NotePlayer.player != null){
        NotePlayer.player.stop();
        NotePlayer.player.release();

    }
}


}
```

Comment: NotePlayer is not imported Also, post your logcat, so it will give better idea, Meanwhile, you can check analyse your memory, whether your dialog may have memory leak or any other issue so its eating up a lot of resources.

Comment: logcat shows this in red when i press the button a second time: E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned

Comment: use Log lib of Android to properly print stack traces and error messages, or you can use breakpoints to follow up issue.